# Little issues with page's layout

Tags: html, css, layout

How to delete automatic 8px white margin on page's right side? With the help of answerers I have fixed it in browsers on desktop, e.g. chrome (v48) and IE (v11). And also fixed it in chrome on mobile, but other mobile browsers still shows that margin. Could anyone please help me with that?

PS.

E.g. https://css-tricks.com/ doesn't have right-border at all on total page

But e.g. http://www.voice.fi/ does have right-border on desktop but not on mobile.

Comment: Unsure what you are seeing as both sites span 100%, but I highly recommend using a reset css to avoid issues like the one you are speaking about.

Comment: What browser and version are you viewing these sites on?

Comment: A brief overview on Reset CSS: Each browser has different defaults for each element and if you start using CSS, things may not display the same across all browsers. A Reset CSS sets all the default values for all elements to either 0 or a default so that no matter the browser, everyone starts at the same point, creating a uniform display across the vast majority of browsers.

Comment: I used http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ CSS reset, and it works perfectly on desktop size, but in mobile size it still shows that border only when i open drop down menu with button.

Comment: Mobile sometimes has things pushed outside the bounds. I'll post an answer on how to combat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Josh S. I found the solution. First, well as you said I used reset CSS from this website: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

And then I used in my screen styles CSS these:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden}
nav {overflow-x: hidden}
```

And voila, now it works in all desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Via our back-and-forth in comments, here's an answer to remove blank space on the right in mobile.

CSS

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now perfectly with IE and chrome on desktop, also in mobile chrome, but in mobile with different browsers, like Browser or UC Browser HD, it still shows that border....but I checked that e.g. http://www.voice.fi/ doesn't show that border in mobile's different browsers at all

Comment: Odd, based off the information you have given, that's all I can suggest

Comment: I tried it in firefox on mobile, and in there it shows also border...it appears to work only in chrome on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this at the top of your CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    paddding: 0;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This removes the automatic 8px (in Safari) margin of the body.

Comment: And also it may be added `!important`.

Comment: thanks, it removed the border in ie, but still in chrome it shows the border on mobile sizes.

Comment: @johnc.j. The use of `!important` here is unnecessary, and is also bad practise. Writing CSS correctly is a better solution.

Comment: @RedRose That's odd. Do you have any CSS that could possibly cause this?

Comment: ... I should add to my words, that I mentioned `!important` only for a case of userscript. As Daniel said, in general case, it is a bad practise.